# C# Use of unassigned local variable exception

Tags: c#

I know there are plenty of other people asking basically this exact question, but for some reason, all their answers do not work. My code is as follows:

```
bool timerRun = false;
DateTime startTimer, endTimer;
TimeSpan span;

if(timerRun == false){
    startTimer = DateTime.Now;
    timerRun = true;
}
if(timerRun == true){
    endTimer = DateTime.Now;
    timerRun = false;
    span = endTimer - startTimer; //can also be span = endTimer.Subtract(startTimer);
    Console.WriteLine(span.ToString());
}
```

The timerRun boolean is connected to a button, every time it is pressed it changes from true to false and vice versa.

But whenever I run it, it gives me the error of "Use of unassigned local variable 'startTimer'". I have no clue what to do about this issue as no one else seems to have this problem. I know it's probably a newbie mistake on my part, but please forgive me this is driving me crazy.
Thanks

**Edit:** I have now made it runnable by making it an if-else statement and changed

```
DateTime startTimer, endTimer;
TimeSpan span;
```

to

```
DateTime startTimer = new DateTime(), endTimer = new DateTime();
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan();
```

But instead of writing the variable span to the console, it outputs endTimer (DateTime).

Comment: Can I ask why you have the two if statements at all? as written they look useless since you set the boolean to a state that makes it enter both statements anyway

Comment: This is not the entire code, is it?

Comment: You need to identify your DateTime variables as Global to let them stay alive the whole container object is alive. OR static variables within another class which keeps loaded in the memory within the lifespan of your GUI

Comment: Can you post the full code? Does this code get's looped or just executed once?

Comment: could you add the sub/function or whatever block from which this code runs ?

Comment: @AkramQalalwa - Please don't suggest global variables without knowing more about how they would be used... they're evil..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `startTimer` and `endTimer` are local to the method of interest, as I understand. This can't work because you have to retain the state of `startTimer` throughout calls to this method, otherwise it will be reinitialized on each call. Same for `timerRun`. Make them fields of your class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private DateTime startTimer;
  private bool timerRun = false;

  public void Button_Clicked(...)
  {
    if(!timerRun)
    {
      startTimer = DateTime.Now;
      timerRun = true;
    }
    else
    {
      DataTime endTimer = DateTime.Now;
      timerRun = false;
      TimeSpan span = endTimer - startTimer;
      Console.WriteLine(span.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @LachlanMather Promoting these two variables to class fields implies that their values don't "disappear" when you leave a method. They are now part of the "state" of your object, you can use them in a consistent way in all the methods of this class. These are basic object-oriented concepts. Maybe it's time for you to read a little more about the C# language if you intend to use it on a regular basis?

Answer (score 1):

Use if-else construct in place of two ifs. This will make sure only one of the two blocks is executed.Give an initial value to startTimer and endTimer.

```
 bool timerRun = false;
DateTime startTimer = new DateTime(<year>,<month>,<day>,<hour>,<minute>,<second>);
DateTime endTimer = new DateTime(<year>,<month>,<day>,<hour>,<minute>,<second>);
TimeSpan span;

if(timerRun == false){
    startTimer = DateTime.Now;
    timerRun = true;
}
else{
    endTimer = DateTime.Now;
    timerRun = false;
   span = endTimer - startTimer; //can also be span = endTimer.Subtract(startTimer);
Console.WriteLine("Difference in hours " + span.TotalHours);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't output the difference, it outputs endTimer now. But it actually partially-works now.

Comment: moved Console.WriteLine to outside if-else. Check now

Comment: @LachlanMather I suspect that your `timerRun` is somewhat set to true before you first hit the button. Thus the exception in your initial code and the strange result with this modified version.

Comment: @AksheyBhat Moving it outside would not help as this function is run every time the button is pressed, and I only want it to output the span when the timerRun boolean is true. (i.e. you've pressed the button twice)

Comment: you have yourself set the default value of timerun to false. Is it correct? Does have any other source?

Comment: @LachlanMather Please respond to comments, otherwise we won't be able to help you. Or run the debugger and figure out by yourself why the `false` part of your `if` statement is always executed first (most likely the origin of the problem).

Comment: @AksheyBhat there are no other pieces of code that change that variable.

Comment: @LachlanMather Wait a minute, all your variables are local to the method? OK, see my answer.

Comment: @LachlanMather if no other piece of code changes `timerRun` then it will never print the difference as only `if` block will be executed.